# jSerialComm Library and UI thread issue using JFrame. port.openPort(); method is blocking the UI thread and not allowing any updation in frontend

Tags: java, swing, serial-port, jframe, java-threads

I have an assignment to code software to read the data from the serial port and display it in the front end. I have used JFrames for the front end and JSerialcomm library for reading and writing operation but when opening a serial port by calling the method port.openPort(); the UI is getting blocked the JLbel which is supposed to display the incoming data is blocked.

```
    public class mainscreen{

    JLabel jlabel;
    JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                
                mainscreen window = new mainscreen();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
                window.frame.setResizable(true);
                window.frame.setExtendedState(frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                
                ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
                for(int i=0;i<ports.length;i++){
                    System.out.println(ports[i].getDescriptivePortName());
                }
                    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public menubar() {
    initialize();
}
 public void open_port(SerialPort selected_port) {
    selected_port.openPort();
    jlabel.setText("Port Open");
}
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    jlabel = new JLabel("Port Not Open");
    jlabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 18));
    jlabel.setBounds(819, 50, 150, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(jlabel);
 }
}
```

Here I have used the EventQueue.invokeLater method and completed the frontend developement.There is a second screen where the user selects the port and that will invoke the open_port method in the mainscreen class but the jlabel is not getting updated. I checked if the port is open by using isOpen() method and it was. But if I dont callopenPort method and just update the frontend with the selected port name its working (the jlabel is showing the port number).

Please help me with this error, as this is becoming a huge burden. Any help will be much appreciated.

I just want the UI jlabel to update after opening the port. It's some kindoff thread issue which I'm not able to resolve.

Comment: I'd guess this code is blocking the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) - making the GUI become unresponsive.

Comment: Read the serial port information into a `java.util.List` using a Swing `Timer`.  Construct the GUI and load the `List` information in the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).  The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), will teach you the correct way to build Swing GUIs.  Skip the Netbeans section.